# Wrapper working as EXE, but not as DLL (written in C++/CLI, wrapping around C# class)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, dllexport

I want to write a DLL in C# that has to provide some functions (an API). I was disappointed by MSIL code modifiers that promise to provide C# methods as DLL exports. So I'm now trying to get a bridge DLL working, written in C++/CLI, that should just call through to the static C# methods. C++/CLI is new and cryptic for me.

These are the commands I use on the command line:

- Compile C# file to DLL file: `csc /target:library CSharpClass.cs`
- Compile C++/CLI wrapper file to executable: `cl /clr Test.cpp /link user32.lib`
- Compile C++/CLI wrapper file to DLL file: `cl /clr /LD Test.cpp /link user32.lib`
- Run exported function of DLL file: [`winapiexec`](http://rammichael.com/winapiexec)`Test.dll@CppTestFunction`

*In the comments of the C++/CLI file I describe what's happening.*

C# file:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CSharpNamespace {
    public static class CSharpClass {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, string text,
                string caption, int options);

        public static void TestMethod() {
            MessageBox(IntPtr.Zero, "Test", "", 0);
        }
    }
}
```

C++/CLI file:

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>

// It doesn't matter, whether this path is absolute or not:
#using "CSharpClass.dll"

#include <windows.h>

using namespace CSharpNamespace;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void CppTestFunction() {
    CSharpClass::TestMethod();  // Works with EXE; DLL crashes
//    System::Console::Beep();  // Works with EXE and DLL
//    MessageBoxW(NULL, (LPCWSTR)"", (LPCWSTR)"", 0);  // Works with EXE and DLL
}

void main() {
    CppTestFunction();
}
```

Any idea why the DLL version won't successfully call through to the C# code?

Comment: This "winapiexec" utility you are using is a bit crude, especially so when it doesn't tell us what went wrong.  It does require the function you expose to resemble a winapi function.  Yours doesn't.  It is not __stdcall, it doesn't have a return type like BOOL and it doesn't set the error code (SetLastError).  And your C++/CLI assembly is not actually a DLL, that can't be good.  Just don't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hans Passant was right in his comment. Thanks for this hint!

## Working test case

Command lines:

- `csc /target:library CSharpClass.cs`
- `cl /clr /LD TestDll.cpp /link user32.lib`
- `cl DllCallingTestExe.cpp /link TestDll.lib`

`TestDll.cpp`:

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using "CSharpClass.dll"

#include "TestDll.h"

using namespace CSharpNamespace;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall CppTestMethod() {
    CSharpClass::TestMethod();
}
```

`TestDll.h`:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall CppTestMethod();
```

`DllCallingTestExe.cpp`:

```
#include "TestDll.h"

void main() {
    CppTestMethod();
}
```